# localhost sent an invalid response. ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Tags: nginx, http2

I am working on enabling http2 in nginx docker. I am getting this error when I calling to localhost. My nginx configuration file as below.

```
server {
listen       2020 http2;
server_name  localhost;

#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    root           html;
#    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#    fastcgi_index  index.php;
#    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
#    include        fastcgi_params;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
}
```

Http2 listen port is 2020. I have exposed it to 2020 when the container is started.

```
docker run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 -p 2020:2020 -v 
/home/pubudu/work/nginx/nginx-tms/config/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro  
nginx:latest
```

This is the tutorial link:
[How To Set Up Nginx with HTTP/2 Support on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-with-http-2-support-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Do i need to use port 443 ? is it mandatory ?
(I didn't use ssl for this)

If i curl this url, response like below.

*Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: " to save to a file.*

I know that the page is transferred as a binary in http2. I want get the nginx index page as a response.

your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution for this. It is needed to enable SSL in nginx in order to achieve http2. I tried it and it's working well. I found the answer from this link.

[How To Set Up Nginx with HTTP/2 Support on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-with-http-2-support-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Now my config file as below.

```
server {
listen       443 ssl http2;
server_name  localhost;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.key;


#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    root           html;
#    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#    fastcgi_index  index.php;
#    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
#    include        fastcgi_params;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Curl does not support HTTP/2 over HTTP (h2c) directly and insists on the upgrade method as detailed [in this post](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http2.html):

> **Over an http:// URL**
>   If CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION is set to CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0, libcurl will include an upgrade header in the initial request to the host to allow upgrading to HTTP/2. Possibly we can later introduce an option that will cause libcurl to fail if not possible to upgrade. Possibly we introduce an option that makes libcurl use HTTP/2 at once over http://

Nginx does not support HTTP/2 and HTTP/1 over the same clear text channel (see [this enhancement request](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/816)) hence it does not work with curl.

You can try using [nghttp2](https://nghttp2.org/documentation/nghttp.1.html) or [h2c](https://github.com/fstab/h2c) instead of curl but not sure if that works though not sure if they do. The reality is HTTP/2 is best negotiated over HTTPS and many tools (including all the browsers) only use HTTP/2 over HTTPS [because of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788904/why-do-web-browsers-not-support-h2c-http-2-without-tls).

Comment: Thank for your help. I installed curl with http2 support. I followed this link to enable http2 support   https://askubuntu.com/questions/884899/how-do-i-install-curl-with-http2-support

Comment: OK I assumed you had Curl with http2 support, however even with that it won’t work without HTTPS.