# x/net/http2: ConnState Unable to track

Tags: http, go, tcp, http2, grpc-go

`net/http` package `Server` struct in the SDK have `ConnState func(net.Conn, ConnState)`, But not exists in the 'Server' struct of 'x/net/http2'

With the `h2c` feature, when the state variable is converted to `http.StateHijacked` , I will no longer know the subsequent state of the connection.

I expect to be able to follow the status of this TCP connection until it is closed.

Is there such a function or a flexible solution? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should not use this code in your production.

From x/net/http2:

> This is a work-in-progress HTTP/2 implementation for Go.

For your h2c support there is information:

> ServeConn serves HTTP/2 requests on the provided connection and blocks until the connection is no longer readable.

> ServeConn starts speaking HTTP/2 assuming that c has not had any reads or writes. It writes its initial settings frame and expects to be able to read the preface and settings frame from the client. If c has a ConnectionState method like a *tls.Conn, the ConnectionState is used to verify the TLS ciphersuite and to set the Request.TLS field in Handlers.

> ServeConn does not support h2c by itself. Any h2c support must be implemented in terms of providing a suitably-behaving net.Conn.

H2C is not supported with HTTP/2, there are few technical reason why they cut that support. More information you can find in the following Stack thread: [Why do web browsers not support h2c (HTTP/2 without TLS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788904/why-do-web-browsers-not-support-h2c-http-2-without-tls)

You should not know state of connection, you should rely on the language library. If you need to check if connection can accept new connection, you have function here: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/http2#ClientConn.CanTakeNewRequest

---

Just to take more context, I have one question: Why do you need to know connection state in your application? It is a logic that should be hidden from your app.