# Changing the NGINX config statement from `listen 80;` to `listen 80 http2;`

Tags: nginx

Inside NGINX config file:

```
http {

        server {
                listen 80;
                server_name sample.com;

                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                }
        }

        server {
                listen 80;
                server_name example.com;

                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
                }
        }
}
```

The above config works fine and web browser is able to access websites and show their content.

But, when I change `listen 80;` statement to `listen 80 http2;`, the web browser downloads a file rather than showing webpages of *sample.com* and *example.com*. Why is that?

Comment: Maybe because the browser doesn't support http2 without tls, as mentioned in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788904/why-do-web-browsers-not-support-h2c-http-2-without-tls

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh Seems like that's the answer! =)

Answer (score 0):

**Content-Type: text/html** should in Response Headers (like below)

Maybe you should config http2's Response Headers

[image]