# How to force browsers to use HTTP/2 protocol w/o TLS?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, browser, http2

I have a nodejs based web app that uses `http2` library of `nodejs`. I start my app

```
HTTP/2 server is listening on port 3000. PID: 238718.
```

and want to check app's homepage: http://localhost:3000/

I have an error in Chrome browser: `ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE`

I know that Chrome uses HTTP/2 over TLS (HTTPS).

Does any possibility exist to use HTTP/2 w/o HTTPS in a browsers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do web browsers not support h2c (HTTP/2 without TLS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788904/why-do-web-browsers-not-support-h2c-http-2-without-tls)

Answer (score 2):

> Does HTTP/2 require encryption?
> No. After extensive discussion, the Working Group did not have consensus to require the use of encryption (e.g., TLS) for the new protocol.

> However, some implementations have stated that they will only support HTTP/2 when it is used over an encrypted connection, **and currently no browser supports HTTP/2 unencrypted.**

Source: https://http2.github.io/faq/#does-http2-require-encryption

Note that you can just use a self signed certificate for local development