# How do I adjust Go's http Client (or Transport) to mimic curls --http2-prior-knowledge flag?

Tags: go, curl, http2

I'm interacting with a server (that is out of my control) in which protocol upgrade is not performed by the server if a request contains content (POST, PUT, PATCH with payload). It's unclear exactly what the issue with the server is, but I noticed that when I query with `--http2-prior-knowledge`, the protocol is upgraded:

```
❯ curl -i -PUT --http2-prior-knowledge  http://localhost:8081/document/v1/foo -d '{"fields": {"docid": "123"}}'
HTTP/2 200 
date: Tue, 08 Nov 2022 13:26:50 GMT
content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8
vary: Accept-Encoding
content-length: 78
```

The same request without `--http2-prior-knowledge` is stuck at HTTP/1.1. This seems closer to the default behaviour of Go's HTTP client

```
❯ curl -i -PUT --http2 http://localhost:8081/document/v1/foo -d '{"fields": {"docid": "123"}}'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 08 Nov 2022 01:37:17 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 78
```

When I call this same API using Go's default client, the protocol is not upgraded. I've tried setting `ForceAttemptHTTP2: true` on the transport, but each `http.Response` contains a `.Proto` of `HTTP/1.1`

I think what I need to understand is how I can mimic curl's prior-knowledge flag in Go. Is this possible?

Comment: The package docs state _"To explicitly enable HTTP/2 on a transport, use `golang.org/x/net/http2` and call `ConfigureTransport`. See the package docs for more about HTTP/2."_. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by specifying a custom `http2.Transport` which skipped TLS dial. The ideal solution, in retrospect, is to use an SSL  certificate (self-signed is sufficient) which would better guarantee the use of HTTP2. Leaving some links for posterity

```golang
c := &http.Client{
        // Skip TLS Dial
        Transport: &http2.Transport{
           AllowHTTP: true,
           DialTLS: func(netw, addr string, cfg *tls.Config) (net.Conn, error) {
              return net.Dial(netw, addr)
           },
        },
}
```

And links:

- [Why do web browsers not support h2c (HTTP/2 without TLS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788904/why-do-web-browsers-not-support-h2c-http-2-without-tls)
- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14141