# Why IIS support HTTP/2 only through HTTPS and not HTTP ?

Tags: iis, http2, iis-10

When i read the doc, it's look like IIS support HTTP2 only over a TSL connection (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis - IIS currently supports HTTP/2 only over TLS). Why a such behavior ?

Comment: Because all major browser vendors support http2 over TLS only ... although it’s not in the standard ... browser support requirements have made https mandatory on HTTP2

Comment: so the question is why all major browser vendors support http2 over TLS only ?

Comment: bit of googling and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076231/why-do-browser-implementations-of-http-2-require-tls

Comment: You might also refer to the FAQ, https://http2.github.io/faq/#does-http2-require-encryption HTTP in HTTP/2 was more of a trade-off to make the protocol suitable to be published, while in practice most vendors already go HTTPS only as the other comment indicated.