# what's meaning of insecure connection in grpc?

Tags: ssl, grpc, http2

gRPC is based on `http2` which must be use ssl.
But I found I can create use insecure server.

I want to know `insecure` means that don't use ssl or use predefined certificate for http2?

Answer (score 14):

HTTP/2 does not insist on SSL/TLS. But all web browsers only implement HTTP2 over SSL/TLS [because of problems when using it over plaintext HTTP over the Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076231/why-do-browser-implementations-of-http-2-require-tls). So if not using a web browser but another HTTP/2 client than you can use HTTP/2 without SSL/TLS.

So yes insecure gRPC is using an unencrypted HTTP/2 connection (h2c). Though [some implementations do not support this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/555), similar to how web browsers do not support unencrypted HTTP/2 (h2c).

Comment: The answer is correct, but I would replace the "plaintext" with "unencrypted". Since HTTP/2 still uses a binary (and not textual) frame encoding.