# cpu usage comparison of http2 and http1 requests

Tags: apache, cpu-usage, http2, http-1.1

Sending **400 HTTP/1** requests is generating **90%** CPU usage,

while, sending **150 HTTP/2** requests is generating **80%** CPU usage.

Why does **HTTP/2** take more CPU usage relative to **HTTP/1** using curl command?

Comment: Are they both HTTPS?

Comment: no only http2 runs https.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comments you are not comparing like for like. You are comparing:

- HTTP/1.1 over **HTTP**
- HTTP/2 over HTTPS

A better comparison would be:

- HTTP/1.1 over **HTTPS**
- HTTP/2 over HTTPS

And then I would expect numbers to be similar or even slightly in favour of HTTP/2.

HTTPS does add some overheads to HTTP requests and [while it is not particularly noticeable for most websites](https://istlsfastyet.com/) nowadays with the increase in CPUs on most servers, performance tests that make a single request (unlike a typical website which makes multiple requests for the page, the CSS, the Javascript...etc.), will see a proportionally larger impact like you have noticed because the first request has to complete the HTTPS handshake to set up the encryption. For a website, that makes multiple requests on the same connection the cost of that first request becomes proportionally less as more requests are used.

HTTPS is increasingly becoming the norm and is expected on websites now with browsers increasingly highlighting insecure HTTP-only sites (e.g. [Google Chrome](https://www.blog.google/technology/safety-security/say-yes-https-chrome-secures-web-one-site-time/), [Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/04/30/deprecating-non-secure-http/) and [Apple Safari](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/apple-safari-http-warning/)) all sites should look to move to HTTPS as soon as they can in my opinion. HTTP/2 helps with the push to that as [it gives performance improvements](https://www.tunetheweb.com/blog/http-versus-https-versus-http2/) and is only available over HTTPS for [both ideological and technical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076231/why-do-browser-implementations-of-http-2-require-tls).