# Cannot see the Http-Settings Header in the nghttp2 example

Tags: c, http2, nghttp2

I am currently trying to learn nghttp2 and was trying to execute the client code which is provided at the bottom of this page:

https://nghttp2.org/documentation/tutorial-client.html

I executed the above C code doing the following:

```
./libevent-client URL
```

My Server is Windows IIS 10.0 and i want to see the http2-settings frame in the output of the header. As of now it is showing the following output:

```
Connected
Request headers:
:method: GET
:scheme: https
:authority: MY URL
:path: /

Response headers from stream ID=1:
:status: 200
content-type: text/html
last-modified: Mon, 01 Jul 2019 17:57:17 GMT
accept-ranges: bytes
etag: "c7c5406c3630d51:0"
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
date: Mon, 08 Jul 2019 16:02:27 GMT
content-length:51
All headers received

<html><head>Hello</head><html>
```

I need to know what should i need in the code to see whether the http-settings are getting passed on with the request. I know that following function does the work of sending the SETTINGS frames with the request:

```
static void send_client_connection_header(http2_session_data *session_data) {
  nghttp2_settings_entry iv[1] = {
      {NGHTTP2_SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS, 100}};
  int rv;

  /* client 24 bytes magic string will be sent by nghttp2 library */
  rv = nghttp2_submit_settings(session_data->session, NGHTTP2_FLAG_NONE, iv,
                               ARRLEN(iv));
  if (rv != 0) {
    errx(1, "Could not submit SETTINGS: %s", nghttp2_strerror(rv));
  }
}
```

I also don't know what is the tag we use for HTTP-Settings in http2 protocol just like for method we have ":method", for scheme ":scheme" etc. I couldn't find it even in the RFC.

Comment: You can use 'good old' Wireshark to sniff packets in flight to confirm with your own eyes that SETTINGS frame is sent.

Comment: @SoumyaKanti Thanks !! Sometimes we forget the simple basic stuff. It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP/2 settings frame is not an HTTP Header - it is a separate message sent at the beginning of connections. Therefore it is not possible to display it like as if it was an HTTP Header.

HTTP/2 contains many such non-visible control frames:

- SETTINGS frame to define how the connection is used
- WINDOW_UPDATE frame to implement flow control
- PRIORITY frame to reprioritise streams (and therefore responses).

...etc.

Typically browsers and servers do not show these Control messages to the user or even in developer tools. Chrome allows you to see them using the `chrome://net-export` URL, or you can use a network sniffing tool like Wireshark to see them.

One of the easiest ways however, and a very good way to learn HTTP/2 by examining the raw frames, is to use the nghttpd tool (which is part of the nghttp2 suite) to create an HTTP/2 server that can log any messages sent to it when run in verbose mode, like this:

```
nghttpd -v 443 server.key server.crt
```

I discuss how to do this in more depth in my book, which you can preview online for free for 5 mins a day at: https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/http2-in-action/chapter-4/176

One thing I should say is that when connecting over non-encrypted HTTP/1.1 (as opposed to HTTPS) and then upgrading to HTTP/2 then the Settings are sent in an HTTP Header (called [HTTP2-Settings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-3.2.1)) but this is a special case, and when this is sent the message is an HTTP/1.1 message. Additionally browsers only support HTTP/2 over HTTPS ([for good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076231/why-do-browser-implementations-of-http-2-require-tls)) and I see you are using HTTPS too. So I would ignore this and only mentioning it for completeness sake.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. What i want to do is that i have to send for example 2000 settings parameters in a single frame to perform a denial of service attack (on a server i am authorized to do). For that, I added the statement nghttp2_settings_entry iv[2000] = {[0 ... 1999] = {NGHTTP2_SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS, 100}}; but somehow its not able to create enough traffic. Anyways, thanks again, I will take care of the knowledge which you shared.

Comment: Setting 2000 concurrent streams won’t necessarily create a DoS. It will just process them in order it gets to them. This may be slow, but other clients should still be able to connect and process them as only that connection should be held up (depending how IIS handles this of course as I am not an IIS expert). There have been IIS issues about DoS where, due to how it handles certain the SETTINGS frame, it CAN cause a DoS when sending many SETTINGS frames or values (https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-publishes-security-alert-on-iis-bug-that-causes-100-cpu-usage-spikes/).

Comment: This is exactly what I am working on. The IIS Server Multiple SETTINGS frame issues. Thanks again for all your Help. You have been life savior !

Comment: NP. If this answers the question then you should accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers