# Http2 without tls in rust hyper 0.14

Tags: rust, http2, hyper

I was trying create http2 backend in rust and using hyper 0.14. It work perfect with tls but does not work without tls. not on localhost as well.

```
  let addr = sc.addr();
  let incoming = AddrIncoming::bind(&addr)?;
  let builder = Server::builder(incoming).http2_only(true);
  builder.serve(make_svc_single_req).await
```

it should serve webpage without tls on http2.

Comment: How did you test whether it works? Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076231/why-do-browser-implementations-of-http-2-require-tls

Comment: Hey @maxy thanks for that question refference. It means browser doesn't support H2c as of now